# ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException in solr wordbreaksolrspellchecker getsuggesstion

Tags: java, solr, solrj

We are escaping the special characters for exact search (" ") and it works fine, except for few cases where it throws

```
Arrayindex out of bounds exception at org.apache.solr.spelling.wordbreaksolrspellchecker.getSuggestions
```

search text : "PRINTING 9-27 TEST CARDS ADD-ON MATT LAMINATION ON 2-SIDE OF TEST CARDS PER BOX OF 100 PCS". the config is spellcheck.dictionary is default and commented the spellcheck.dictionary wordbreak
we cannot apply any patch now, checked the issue LUCENE-5494
any of you suggest any work around to get the results in-spite of the exception. any configuration changes to suppress suggest or spellcheck. commenting word break dictionary also didn't help. solr version 4.10.4

Comment: Please show the piece of code that is producing the exception if you want suggestions on how to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Due to security reasons, I cannot post anything related to code and sorry for the minimal information in the query.
Anyways It might be useful to someone like me. The reason even after commenting the wordbreak dictionary its still showing the exception is,the changes that were made in the solrconfig.xml file was not reflected. I was testing in my local machine which is a standalone environment. Restarting the container (weblogic) doesn't reflect the changes snd reloading the core through admin screen also didn't help. So import and reloadset and then restarting the container did the trick.